# Constructing Angles

Tags: euclidean-geometry, geometric-construction

I am a high school student, while solving the 'construction' chapter of my textbook I realized that it is not possible to construct every angle using a compass and a straight edge.
why is it not possible to construct every angle using a
compass(collapsible) and a straight edge?For example,i observed that
it is not possible to construct an angle of 40 degree.
**how can i determine whether an angle is constructible using a
compass(collapsible) and a straight edge or not?**

Comment: You can create angles like $90^\circ , 60^\circ, 45^\circ$ and $30^\circ$ quite easily. You must also be knowing that you can create their bisectors as well. So, considering the smallest easily constructible angle i.e. $30^\circ$, construct its bisector to get $15^\circ$ and then bisect it again to get $7.5^\circ$. You can bisect it further however it'll be tedious. So, in a nutshell, using a compass and ruler, you can construct angles which are multiples of $7.5^\circ$.